# Apache Camel FTP vs FTP2

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

What is the difference between Camel ftp and ftp2? I want to write a new ftp endpoint but I am getting confused between these. 
Also if possible do state which one is better than other and why.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same today. The reason there documentation url says ftp2 is because many many years ago the old ftp component were refactored for Camel 2.0, and had some extra options and therefore we created a ftp2 url for its documentation.

The documentation today for the FTP component is best viewed (at this time of writing) on github at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/main/docs/ftp-component.adoc

The Camel website and documentation is in process of a revamp to happen later this year, so you can then again view all docs from the Apache site.